# update Ad-Hoc distribution file

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I need to override an ad-hoc distribution file on a testers device. I'm confused with the apps version number and the build number. what number do I need to change to make sure that the new version will override the existing one?

`Bundle versions string, short` or the `Bundle Version`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*CFBundleVersion (Bundle version)* should be the  `Info.plist` **key** and the *bundle version string* should be the **Value** that specifies the **build version number** of the bundle. This value is a monotonically increased string, comprised of one or more period-separated integers. This value cannot be localized.

```
NSString *versionNum = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleVersion"]; // X.Y.Z format.

NSString *versionNum = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"] //  X.Y format.
```

Comment: Hello Ramshad, thanks for your answer but which number needs to get changed when an updated app version should be distributed to the testers again?

Comment: This value is a monotonically increased string, comprised of one or more period-separated integers.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses the Version Number when you upload your app to the App Store. The information in iTunes Connect and your `info.plist` need to be the same.

The build number is a separate entity (as far as I know) that you can increase with every build or otherwise.

For your updated app, you can always add `.1` to the version string.